# eWay Payment gateway POST method getting inccorect result

Tags: soap, payment-gateway

i am using eWay payment gateway for this i used URL to POST data **https://secure-au.sandbox.ewaypayments.com/Process**

But getting response like this: {"Message":"Not Found","Errors":null}

and after that when i post on this url : https://api.sandbox.ewaypayments.com/GetAccessCodeResult.json getting correct json but all the data is null or some random data and getting ResponseMessage = S5099 ( as I seen I document is for S5099  Incomplete (Access Code in progress/incomplete) but i already getting access code with this url https://api.sandbox.ewaypayments.com/CreateAccessCode.json )

All the above process is with eWay payment gateway's SOAP call.

Answer (score 0):

- 1) eWAY allows many method to call gateway API, It is not depend only for SOAP.
- 2) After Creating Access code with first step. Pls confirm that you are sending all required information to  https://secure-au.sandbox.ewaypayments.com/Process. (Please see page. no. 30 of http://www.eway.com.au/docs/api-documentation/rapid-3-0-documentation-au.pdf).
- 3) After step 2 you will get message as you are current getting.
- 4) To get Access code result you must use 'GET' method. It does not allow 'POST' method. (Please see page. No. 33 of above PDF.)
- 5) Make sure you are using correct sandbox username & password other wise it will gave you system error as you are current facing.